# ado.net Sqlite using framework 4.8

Tags: sqlite, visual-studio-2022

I did not the connection string based on the followed steps.

visual studio 2022

intalled the packages for entityframework 6,System.Data.SQLite

installed the Sqlite tools ,still i didnot get the connection string.Please help me any one.

i want solution for this issue